# EntityManager overwrites saveAndFlush

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My problem is as follows:

I use `Java 7` in one project and `Java 8` in the other one. Those two projects communicate with database in different ways that I will explain below.

I save entities in the database from two different projects. Let's call the table `Person`. In one place of the code I use `saveAndFlush` from `JpaRepository` and the other one uses `EntityManager.persist()`. The `saveAndFlush` runs first and saves one `Person` in the table after that, the `EntityManager.persist()` is called to save a different `Person` 3 times in the same table as the `saveAndFlush`. After the `EntityManager.persist()` the `Person` that was saved by `saveAndFlush` gets deleted from database. I am trying to find why it is happening like that but I got stuck. Does anyone have an idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the culprit.
The problem was because a variable in the `Person` class had a `orphanRemoval = true` property

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH },
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person", **orphanRemoval = true**)
    private List<PersonDetail> personDetail= new ArrayList<>();.
```

After removing `orphanRemoval` hibernate stopped removing Entity added by `saveAndFlush()` from another microservice.